# Better way to read multiple CSV files

Tags: pyspark

I have 200 csv files based on dates.  Of which, I require data from 50 files only.  Should I read all 200 files and then filter them based on dates  or  should I read only those 50 needed files? which would be a better option performance wise?

Answer (score 0):

the [`csv`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) method of `DataFrameReader` accepts a list of path to create the dataframe. 
If you know exactly the path you want, just generate a list and use it.